# Como usar o component autocomplete do Material Ui sem erros

Tags: javascript, react, eventos, console, material-ui

Tenho um componente `Autocomplete` do Material UI onde o usuário pesquisa os valores baseado num array de produtos que vem de uma API. O componente está assim, onde `products` é o array, `setPointsProduct` e `setItem` é o meu state. :

```js
<Autocomplete
            value={item}
            id="autocomplete"
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
              if (newValue) {
                const values = newValue.split('-');
                setPointsProduct(values[1]);
                setItem(values[0]);
                document.getElementById('quantity').focus();
              } else {
                toast.error('Selecione um produto');
              }
            }}
            options={products.map(
              product => `${product.name} - ${product.points}`
            )}
            renderInput={params => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label="Produtos"
                required
                className={classes.points}
                autoFocus
                variant="outlined"
              />
            )}
          />
```

O componente funciona mas toda vez que abro o console aparece esse erro:

```
useAutocomplete.js:249 Material-UI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `""`.
You can use the `getOptionSelected` prop to customize the equality test.
```

Como eu posso retirar esse erro? Estou fazendo alguma coisa de errado no componente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Fato

A mensagem está dizendo que tem um valor fornecido na propriedade `value` que não está presente na lista de opções.

## Motivo

O componente `Autocomplete` está buscando na sua lista de opções um valor que não esta presente.

Imagino que tenhamos a seguinte lista de produtos.

```js
const products = [
  { name: "Arroz", points: 100 },
  { name: "Feijão", points: 120 },
  { name: "Açucar", points: 80 },
  { name: "Beterraba", points: 32 },
  { name: "Alface", points: 5 },
  { name: "Carne", points: 30 },
  { name: "Chicoria", points: 20 },
  { name: "Leite", points: 12 }
];
```

As opções do autocomplete de acordo ao seu código:

```js
options={products.map(product => `${product.name} - ${product.points}`)}
```

Será:

```js
const opcoes = [
  'Arroz - 100',
  'Feijão - 120',
  'Açucar - 80',
  'Beterraba - 32',
  'Alface - 5',
  'Carne - 30',
  'Chicoria - 20',
  'Leite - 12',
]
```

Ao fazer o `setItem(values[0])` você está dizendo que o valor (propriedade `value`) será apenas o nome do seu produto, e não o valor completo que você forneceu nas opções, que é composto pelo `nome - pontos`.
Nesse caso o `Autocomplete` não irá conseguir determinar a **equalidade** dos valores entre o selecionado `nomeApenas` e valor `nome - pontos`.

## Solução

Seguindo o que você demonstrou, poderíamos corrigir com a propriedade [`getOptionSelected`](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/).
 
Essa propriedade é utilizada quando você precisa determinar uma forma diferente de testar a equalidade entre o valor da propriedade `value` e sua lista de opções.
Ela é uma função que recebe dois valores, o primeiro é a opção e o segundo é o valor. Dessa forma você pode aplicar a mesma regra que você usa para setar o valor.

```js
getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
  const values = option.split("-");
  return values[0] === value;
}}
```

Aqui segue uma implementação da solução aplicada.

[image: Edit Button]

## Recomendação

Não sei qual é o real uso. Mas recomendo que você use o `value` com o próprio objeto contido no array. Use as propriedades `getOptionSelected` e `getOptionLabel` para controlar o que esta selecionado e o que é visualizado.
Aqui está uma implementação usando essas duas propriedades controlando a selecão e visualização.

[image: Edit Button]

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive o mesmo problema e após ler a solução do Jairon, consegui resolver. Compartilho abaixo o resultado final, com parametrização que permite que o componente seja utilizado para diversos conteúdos diferentes:

```html
import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete, { AutocompleteChangeReason, AutocompleteChangeDetails } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    campo: {
      margin: "2% 2%",
      width: "98%"
    },
  })
);

type AutoProps=
{
  nome: string,
  label: string,
  classe: string,
  valor: any,
  habilitado: boolean,
  conteudo: any [],
  colunas: {id: string, desc: string}
  onchange: ((event: ChangeEvent<{}>, value: any, reason: AutocompleteChangeReason,  details?: AutocompleteChangeDetails<any> | undefined, campo?: string) => void)
}


export default function SelecaoAuto({nome, label, classe, valor, conteudo, habilitado, colunas, onchange}: AutoProps) {

    const classes=useStyles();

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            className={classe ? classe : classes.campo}
            id={nome}
            options={conteudo}
            getOptionLabel={cliente => cliente[colunas.desc]}
            getOptionSelected={(option: any, value: any) => option[colunas.id] === value[colunas.id]}
            onChange={(event, value, reason, details) => onchange(event, value, reason, details, nome)}
            disabled={!habilitado}
            value={valor}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label} placeholder={label} variant="outlined" />}
        />
    );
}
```

Na função onchange no componente que utiliza o componente acima, você pode setar o state (optei por não utilizar o state no componente customizado).

Exemplo:

```html
    const onChangeRecebimentosAutoComplete = (event: ChangeEvent<{}>, value: any, reason: AutocompleteChangeReason, details?: AutocompleteChangeDetails<any> | undefined, campo?: string) =>
    {
typeof reason, details, typeof details)
      if(campo)
      {
        if (value[campo])
        {
          setRecebimento({...recebimento, [campo]: value[campo]});
          console.log('setrecebimnento: ', recebimento.id_cli, value[campo], campo);
        }
      }
    }
```

E na chamada do componente, eu utilizo também uma chamada à uma função para identificar o item da matriz passado como valor:

```html
    const RetornaCliente = (idcli: number) =>
    {
        console.log('retorna cliente: ', idcli);
        let clesc = undefined;
        let indice=clientes.findIndex((cliente:any) => cliente.id_cli===idcli)
        if(indice>=0)
        {
            clesc=clientes[indice];
        }
        console.log('retorna cliente fim:',clesc);
        return clesc;
    }


<SelecaoAuto valor={RetornaCliente(recebimento.id_cli)} nome='id_cli' label='Cliente' classe={classes.textoform} conteudo={clientes} habilitado={true} colunas={{id: 'id_cli', desc: 'nome_cli'}} onchange={onChangeRecebimentosAutoComplete}/>
```